# Binding Ojet Tree view with JSON data

Tags: oracle-jet

I am trying to bind the JSON data to the tree view. My html code for tree view is as follows

```
 <oj-tree-view id="treeview"
                                  data=treeDataSource
                                  item.renderer=oj.KnockoutTemplateUtils.getRenderer('item_template', true)
                                  selection-mode="multiple"
                                  aria-label="Tree View">


                    </oj-tree-view>

                    <script type="text/html" id="item_template">

                        <li>
                          <span class="oj-treeview-item-icon"></span><span class="oj-treeview-item-text" data-bind="text: id"></span>

                        </li>
                    </script>
```

I am getting the JSON data using restUrl and assinging it to ko.observablearray "folderData" as shown below in my treeview.js.

```
  $.getJSON(restUrl, function (data) {
                        self.folderData(data);

                    });
 self.treeDataSource =new oj.JsonTreeDataSource(self.folderData());
```

The tree view is not getting generated and it seems to be problem with item.renderer. 
I am getting the following error
[item_renderer error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSfrH.png)
Please help me in solving this issue

Comment: Before I stage your code have you printed the result of your service to make sure it's returning data?

Comment: The rest url returns the following output [{"attr":{"id":"contractsdata.csv","title":"contractsdata.csv"}}]

Comment: Ok if someone doesn't beat me to it I'll stage your code tonight and help lead you to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You check with below solution

```
 <oj-tree-view id="treeview" 
                      data="[[treeDataSource]]" 
                      item.renderer="[[oj.KnockoutTemplateUtils.getRenderer('item_template', true)]]" 
                      selection-mode="multiple" 
                      aria-label="Tree View with JSON Data">
</oj-tree-view>
```

Refer this [document](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=treeView&demo=json)